# How to get rid of duplicate in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can get rid of duplicate and display record(s) using jQuery dataTables in asp.net mvc.

```
public ActionResult FilterData()
{
    var results = db.Cbps.Where(a => a.SDATE == a.SDATE);
    List<string> filterdDate = new List<string>();

    foreach (var item in results)
    {             
        filterdDate.Add(item.SDATE);
    }

    var obj = new { data = filterdDate };

    //var da = obj;
    return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#abc').DataTable({

            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Filter/FilterData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [

                { "data": "SDATE", "autoWidth": true }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Results with duplicate**

2020-04-18
2020-04-18
2020-04-18
2020-04-18
2020-04-17
2020-04-17
2020-04-17
2020-04-17

**Without duplicate**

2020-04-18
2020-04-17

Comment: `Distinct()` result before returning it to the view?!

Comment: what is that? `(a => a.SDATE == a.SDATE)` this is always true

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code to do the following:

```
var filteredDate = db.Cbps.Where(a => a.SDATE == a.SDATE).Select(c => c.SDATE).Distinct();

var obj = new { data = filterdDate };

return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

The LINQ extension method Distinct() will return unique data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashSet  to remove duplicates

```
var filterdDate = new HashSet<string>(results);

var obj = new { data = filterdDate };

 return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```